# how to make facebook recognize my webpage images

Tags: facebook, sharing, thumbnails

i developed a website
ut when i share any page 
in facebook

facebook should recognize my page
and select images to select a thumbnail

but this do not happen in my website
as if facebook can not recognize my page

or cannot read it and select images from it
what should i do

to let facebook recognize my page 
and load all images in the page to 
navigate left and right to select a thumb for the shared page

Comment: Is this sharing via a Like button on the page? Do you also mean pasting the URL into a status update?

Comment: You could look at the source code of pages that Facebook shows a selection for to see if there's anything special there.

Comment: On the few occasions I've shared links to my own pages with Facebook (admittedly from the Facebook site itself, rather than from my own pages) it's never had any problem recognising, and offering, images to share. [Does your page conform to a valid doctype?](http://validator.w3.org/) Are the images in an obscure format? Is there any attempt to prevent hot-linking images from your site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the question has already been answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987195/how-does-facebook-know-what-image-to-parse-out-of-an-article) Here is another useful [link](http://grafikdesign.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/facebook-sharespecifying-meta-tags-fbml-audio-flash-video-action-bar/). Thanks for asking. It made me find out something I can use.

Update: After trying it and finding it not to work I tried the method in [this](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=266776) post. It initially didn't work, but that was because I forgot to upload the image. So it may be the case that the original method may still work. Here's the template I used in my head section:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="your title">
<meta property="og:description" content="your description">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yoursite.com/your-image.jpg">
```

Update 2: If it seems that Facebook isn't recognizing your code, try their [lint tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/). This does two things. The obvious one is that it reports any errors in your code. The second is that it refreshes Facebook's cache of the page. I had two pages where the new code wasn't recognized until I did this.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the FB lint tool, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

From my own tests, Facebook should find images on your site with no problem, so long as they appear directly in the html (as `<img src="path/to/img.png" />`<sup>1</sup>) and not via css (`background-image: url(path/to/img.png);`).

[This is my own-site test, at: http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/fbookImg.html](http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/fbookImg.html), admittedly this doesn't have a 'share this page' button, so requires you to log into Facebook *first*, which might make a difference. But I don't have a Facebook developer account with which to test that theory, unfortunately.

---

1. Either absolute, or relative, paths seem to make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

from my experience using a drupal site the logo was not recognized because the drupal system renders a relative path. changing this to a full path with http:// and refreshing FB's cache should work