# How facebook finds out whether a url shared is a video or an article or an image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Whenever we post any url to facebook, it extracts its data and shows the basic information like title, thumbimage etc. I just want to know how it detects whether the url contains a video and adds a play button on top of the thumbimage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple links to get you on the right track. The short answer is Open Graph, e.g.

```
<meta property="og:image" content=""some content..." />
```

and if those tags aren't available, in simple terms, facebook guesses.

[How Does Facebook Know What Image To Parse Out of An Article?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987195/how-does-facebook-know-what-image-to-parse-out-of-an-article)

Facebook uses the Open Graph Protocol to determine what content is being shared. It is up to the webmasters/developers to insert these tags on their content.

[Webmasters - Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)